# さえ: How to use it?

Tags: particle-も, particle-さえ

What is the difference between the sentences below:

> ビショップ**さえ**取ればいいよ。
>
> ビショップを取り**さえ**すればいいよ。

I also saw on a site that でさえ is the same as さえ in a sentence like 子供さえわかる. But isn't で the 連用形 of だ? I would translate the sentence as below:

> これは子供**でさえ**わかるだろう : Even if you are a kid you should be able to understand this.
>
> これは子供**さえ**わかるだろう : Even a kid should be able to understand this.

And my last question: I saw a translation for 「日本語**さえ**話せない」 which is "you can't even speak Japanese", can I express the same thing by saying 「日本語**も**話せない」? Or does this sentence only mean "you cannot speak Japanese either"?

Answer (score 8):

The first pair is easily understood if you take notice where さえ attaches to.

When you don't know ***what piece*** you should capture, I can only say **ビショップさえ**取ればいいよ; if you don't know ***what action*** you should do to the Bishop (e.g. if you take it, your piece would be eaten too, so which is more favorable?), I can only say ビショップを**取りさえ**すればいいよ.

If your question is only "What should I do in this position?", then both will do.

---

> *I also saw on a site that でさえ is the same as さえ in a sentence like 子供さえわかる.*

Really? They're very different. Since さえ is a 取り立て助詞 "focus particle(?)" that isn't a primary particle, it generally can only come after another case particle (格助詞). What you see as if さえ comes right after a noun is actually either **が**さえ or **を**さえ, but the two (and only they) are usually eaten by 取り立て助詞.

> 子供**さえ**わかる ← 子供**が**わかる "understand children" (or *could be* "children understand")
>
> 子供**にさえ**わかる ← 子供**に**わかる "children can understand" (*lit.* "be understandable to children")

So, the stumbling block here is, in fact, で.

> 子供**でさえ**わかる ← 子供**で**わかる "understand within children / as much as a child can"

This is a case particle, and not a paradigm of copula だ. It's rarely used alone in this sense, though it does exist:

> 子供**で**わからなければ、大人に聞くといい。

But instead it typically appears with 取り立て助詞, such as では, でも, ですら or でさえ.

---

日本語さえ話せない and 日本語も話せない can describe the same situation in most of times, but there is a clear distinction; も comes from "also" thus means it's a deviation from criterion, while さえ implies that itself is a criterion. That is:

> 日本語（○さえ／×も）話せなければ、聞かれても問題ない。
> *It doesn't matter if we're heard, as long as (=if only it's met that) they don't speak Japanese.*