# Confused in determining the rule of composing ～さえ～ば sentence

Tags: grammar

Let's consider the following conditional sentence but without "ONLY".

> ボタンを押せば、ジュースが出る。If you press the button, the juice comes out.

When "ONLY" is inserted with さえ, the conditional sentence becomes as follows.

> A: ボタンを押しさえすれば、ジュースが出る。

## Question

Why do we not use B instead of A?

> B: ボタンさえ押せば、ジュースが出る。

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33409/7810

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both expressions fine.

Eg, Say you were explaining to a foreigner in Japan on using a vending machine who had never used one before. 
You could say something like this,

> All you have to do is ,press the button and a drink will come out.
>
> ボタンを押しさえすれば、ジュースが出る。
>
> All you have to do is study and you will pass.
>
> 勉強さえすれば合格する。

I see where "only" is implied and using "all you have to do" as the meaning "you only have to do...."

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Both A and B are correct. B's also not wrong at all.